# Comparing 2 Times using DateTime instances

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I am trying to make an appointment system. The only problem is that I don't want to let the customer create an appointment if there is another appointment accepted.

I want to leave 1hour between an appointment and another say if appointment A is at 12:00 you cant book appointment between 12:00 and 13:00

here is my code:

```
List<Appointment> acceptedAppointments = new Service1Client().getAllAcceptedAppointments();
```

getting all accepted appointments.

```
foreach (Appointment item in acceptedAppointments)
            {
                if (item.Appointment_DateTime.Date == myDate.Date)
                {
                    if (myDate.AddHours(1) > item.Appointment_DateTime)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
```

I dont know exactly what I need to do here if someone can help it would be great thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bool isValidAppointment = true;

// Go through all accepted appointments
foreach (Appointment item in acceptedAppointments)
{
    // Check if the difference between the appointments is less than 60 minutes
    if (item.Appointment_DateTime.Substract(myDate).Duration.TotalMinutes < 60)
    {
        // If so, set bool to indicate invalid appointment and stop validation
        isValidApopintment = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (isValidAppointment)
{
    // Handle valid appointment
}
else
{
    // Handle invalid appointment
}
```

This can be shortened to:

```
bool isValidApointment = acceptedAppointments.Any(x => x.Substract(myDate).Duration.TotalMinutes < 60);
```